# Linq - Correct format for Left Join

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to linq... and I am wondering if I am doing it right..

Here's my code...

```
var result = from a in ctx.ItemReceipts
             join b in ctx.ItemReceiptStatusTypes on a.Status equals b.ItemReceiptStatusTypeID
             join c in ctx.PurchaseOrders on a.ReferenceID equals c.PurchaseOrderID
             into leftJoinItemReceipts 
             from d in leftJoinItemReceipts.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where a.ItemReceiptID.Equals(ItemReceiptID)
             select new
             {
                 CItemReceiptID = a.ItemReceiptID,
                 CTransactionNumber = a.TransactionNumber,
                 CRemarks = a.Remarks,
                 CStatus = a.Status,
                 CStatusType = b.Description,
                 CReferenceID = a.ReferenceID,
                 CReferenceTypeID = a.ReferenceTypeID,
                 CTransactionDate = a.TransactionDate,
                 CDateReceived = a.DateReceived,
                 CTotalCost = a.TotalCost,
                 CPONumber = d.PONumber                     
             };
```

It runs perfectly... but I really can't understand the `into` part.. I dunno if it's really a left join but gives me the data that I want... it gives me all data in `itemreceipts` even though they don't have something in common with `PurchaseOrder`....

I need explanation... better a comparison between mysql and linq...

Comment: mysql and linq are two completely different things, is this c# or vb?

Comment: @Sayse this is C#... yes they are.... and I am new to linq... so bear with me.

Comment: You may want to look at this webpage.: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: @jdweng I'm on it.. thanks

Comment: based on this article http://www.basepointers.com/performing-inner-join-cross-join-left-and-right-outer-joins-using-linq-queries.. it is most likely to be `outerjoin`...  it will get all records from both table even though they don't have something in common.

Answer (score 0):

```
from a in ctx.ItemReceipts
join b in ctx.ItemReceiptStatusTypes on a.Status equals b.ItemReceiptStatusTypeID
into leftJoinItemReceipts 
from d in leftJoinItemReceipts.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in ctx.PurchaseOrders on d.ReferenceID equals c.PurchaseOrderID
```

This will do a left join on ItemReceipts and ItemReceiptStatusTypes and then a inner join with PurchaseOrders

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: ItemReceipts will do a inner join with ItemReceiptStatusTypes and the ItemReceiptStatusTypes will be left joined with PurchaseOrders on your query

Comment: it is the same query with mine I guess. the position just interchange.

Comment: ItemReceipts should left join with ItemReceiptStatusTypes  or PurchaseOrders ?

Comment: what I want is ItemReceipt will do inner join in StatusType and ItemReceipt should be left join with PurchaseOrder...

Comment: then urs is correct, if it needs to left join with ItemReceiptStatusTypes follow mine

Comment: Sure sir.... thanks =)